# How does google deal with www.google.com/ncr?

Tags: redirect, header, http-headers

I tried to find out this, and got that http://www.google.com/ncr uses 302(or 301) redirections(not sure if it really is).

and i also got that, the server side redirections(301 and 302) will not change the original referer, i.e. if i visit http://www.google.com/ncr directly, then the request goes to google.com, but nothing in the header can show that i come from http://www.google.com/ncr.

so i wonder how google do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People do this very often with servlets. The servlet would detect a certain pattern and issue a redirect to a conglomerated url. A redirect is directed at the browser. It's like the browser has activated/clicked on a new link.

It is like you entered google.com/abc on the url bar and then entered google.com on the address bar after that. Due to privacy issues, the browser does not let the server know what previous URL it has visited.

Of course, if you are on the same session, going to the same site, google would have both server side and client side cookies tracking you that you just came from another google url. If were a web service provider, I Would certainly exploit knowing your browsing history.

So that, due to your browsing history www.whatever. com would redirect to different pages for different users or sessions.

**Addendum**:

"Due to privacy issues, the browser does not let the server know what previous URL it has visited." is not quite correct.

The more complete spec is

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html

Another reason why google forcing us to use https benefits us.

**Redirect flow of non-secure http**

Let's say we have

- URL A has a link goto B with leads to URL B.
- URL B is a redirect to URL C

The server of URL C will see the referer as URL A, not URL B. That is, the browsers will set the referer to URL A.

**Redirect with cookies**

I believe you should be able to include a setcookie header on a 30x redirect. I have not tried it so I do not know which browser will ignore or honour it.

**BTW**

I have great doubts that my answer is satisfactory for your question. I personally feel it is incomplete and I hope some one comes up with a better answer and you should choose that as the answer. In fact, I think you should unchoose this as the answer so that your question gets back into the pool of unanswered questions. Sorry.

Comment: so '.com/ncr' will set the cookies so '.com' knows it?